# Should we change LOGO or NAME of web app?

Tags: web-app, design

**In general :**

Some time colour scheme and/or icon of your logo doesn't match with template you have. To make app better in looks your both elements must be good.But sometimes page design and logo/header are totally opposite (in contrast , monochromaticity , etc )

So what we should prefer to change DESIGN or LOGO/HEADER ?

---

**Example :**
we  are new-bie web app developer. The biggest problem is we are developer and not designers . We named our app even before its developing phase . But now we think that due to our logo we are facing some problems in designing other elements on page.

our logo is red in colour so we cannot give generally standard BLACK header and was forced to put white header. if header is white we forced keep body element different from white (which oppose standard templates we see in most of web apps)
Plus our logo is bit bigger so header gets bigger automatically.The intentions behind keeping logo big was to make it BOLD and Memorable.

So now we are facing question : should we change logo+name or change design . Please answer .

---

If question is too vast to answer let me know I will make edits.

Comment: This feels like it fits better on http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think you got it all backwards. Branding comes first, then you adjust everything else to your brand. Not being a designer is not a excuse, get one to help you. Otherwise, unless your app is so groundbreaking and unique everyone will want to use it, you'll be in a really unfair competition against professionally designed apps, or even apps made by someone with just a small bit of aesthetic sense

Comment: True words but as a small team and in development phase we cannot go for HIRING anyone experienced can u suggest something on that too ?

Comment: This isn't a UX question, rather one of branding. I agree better answers are likely on [Graphic Design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

The Logo must drive your app color scheme or theme.

Logo design is the first and foremost important aspect of any designing and branding. The logo talks about your product /company and its core values.

The logo design plays a major role in building your branding such as print and web material. The logo colors, fonts, and elements are chosen based on the type of business you do.

So, focus on the logo first and the theme can be changed at any time. If you go with best practices in building your app / website, it won't take much time to change the theme of your app.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you feel the need to make your logo bigger is a clear indication you need to hire a graphic designer. You're an engineer but you want to do the visual design; would you want to use an app that was coded by a designer?

Answer (score -1):

With regard to a red logo know that it can become problematic with other color choices throughout the application. For example, if the red logo puts red into the standard color palette you will have conflicts with using red for alerts or problems within the application.

Comment: I dont know who downvoted on this but it was a good observation. This is problem what i am facing but yah  it cannot be an answer

Comment: @akashraigade, I didn't down vote it but really... this is like saying one of the most used colors in branding is problematic, which doesn't make any sense. And this is why you need a designer. On a side note, what is a standard color palette? And which common mobile framework uses red background for alerts?

Comment: i read near 100 articles on colour schemes of logo , and it apparently says that a web apps mostly use blue , not red,purple,yellow etc. And most of web templates  are designed for blue,black header etc. If u browse renadome 100 web sites most of them are not red

Comment: At the end i need a nice designer  (which i cannot afford) But will try my best to set all things down